# Get the date of next monday, tuesday, etc

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to find the date stamp of monday, tuesday, wednesday, etc. If that day hasn't come this week yet, I would like the date to be this week, else, next week. Thanks!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

See [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)

```
strtotime('next tuesday');
```

You could probably find out if you have gone past that day by looking at the week number:

```
$nextTuesday = strtotime('next tuesday');
$weekNo = date('W');
$weekNoNextTuesday = date('W', $nextTuesday);

if ($weekNoNextTuesday != $weekNo) {
    //past tuesday
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. I just have to find out how to find out if monday has already come. That won't be too hard! Thanks!

Answer (score 90):

I know it's a bit of a late answer but I would like to add my answer for future references.

```
// Create a new DateTime object
$date = new DateTime();

// Modify the date it contains
$date->modify('next monday');

// Output
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

The nice thing is that you can also do this with dates other than today:

```
// Create a new DateTime object
$date = new DateTime('2006-05-20');

// Modify the date it contains
$date->modify('next monday');

// Output
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

To make the range:

```
$monday = new DateTime('monday');

// clone start date
$endDate = clone $monday;

// Add 7 days to start date
$endDate->modify('+7 days');

// Increase with an interval of one day
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$dateRange = new DatePeriod($monday, $dateInterval, $endDate);

foreach ($dateRange as $day) {
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d')."<br />";
}
```

#### References

PHP Manual - [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

PHP Manual - [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

PHP Manual - [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

PHP Manual - [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Answer (score 26):

The question is tagged "php" so as Tom said, the way to do that would look like this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next tuesday'));
```

Answer (score 8):

For some reason, `strtotime('next friday')` display the Friday date of the current week. Try this instead:

```
//Current date 2020-02-03
$fridayNextWeek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('friday next week'); //Outputs 2020-02-14

$nextFriday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next friday'); //Outputs 2020-02-07
```

Comment: i am trying 'next friday' on 14 feb 2020 and it return 18 feb 2020. seems like it's working fine.

Comment: Yes, this is because 'next friday' in this context means the next friday to occur. In English, when we say 'next friday', we tend to mean 'friday next week' - and so your method of attaining friday from next week is correct, though it is not the 'next' friday.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Carbon** library.

Example: Next week friday

```
Carbon::parse("friday next week");
```

Comment: What if friday is in same week?

Comment: For-example, what if tomorrow is friday? The op said, if day hasn't come yet I want it to be this week, else next week. 

Thanks Farid

Answer (score 4):

PHP 7.1:

```
$next_date = new DateTime('next Thursday');
$stamp = $next_date->getTimestamp();
```

PHP manual [getTimestamp()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the dates of the next 7 days?

You could do the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)  
  echo date('d/m/y', time() + 86400 * $i);
```

Check the documentation for the date function for the format you want it in.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't notice the PHP tag - however someone else might be interested in a VB solution:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim d As Date = Now
        Dim nextFriday As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Weekday, DayOfWeek.Friday - d.DayOfWeek(), Now)
        Console.WriteLine("next friday is " & nextFriday)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

*if you want to find Monday then 'dayOfWeek' is 1 if it is Tuesday it will be 2 and so on.*

```
var date=new Date();
getNextDayOfWeek(date, 2);
```

// this is for finding next tuesday

```
function getNextDayOfWeek(date, dayOfWeek) {
// Code to check that date and dayOfWeek are valid left as an exercise ;)

var resultDate = new Date(date.getTime());

resultDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);

return resultDate;
}
```

Hope this will be helpfull to you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP documentation for time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) shows an example of how you can get a date one week out.  You can modify this to instead go into a loop that iterates a maximum of 7 times, get the timestamp each time, get the corresponding date, and from that get the day of the week.