# PHP date next tuesday 1pm

Tags: php

```
$tuesday_slot = strtotime('next tuesday');
```

Above code give me unix time for next tuesday.

How do I get the unix time for e.g next tuesday, 1pm.

Thanks!

Comment: what ever day is today but you always want Tuesday Right ?

Comment: @SunilPachlangia yes, tuesday 1pm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the date of next monday, tuesday, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188728/get-the-date-of-next-monday-tuesday-etc)

Answer (score 2):

Easy :

```
$tuesday_slot = strtotime('next tuesday');
$tuesday_slot = strtotime('+ 13 hours',$tuesday_slot);
echo date("r",$tuesday_slot);
```

or

```
$tuesday_slot = strtotime('next tuesday 1pm');
echo date("r",$tuesday_slot);
```