# Dynamically update date for days PHP

Tags: php, html, date

I've a **HTML** table which have days written on one side of it.
Also it has some random data along with it.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('m/d/Y');
?>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="1">Day</th>
    <th id="2">Date</th>
    <th>Game</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>DATE OF MONDAY HERE</td>
    <td>Golf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>DATE OF TUESDAY</td>
    <td>Swimming</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>DATE OF WEDNESDAY</td>
    <td>Tennis</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>DATE THURSDAY</td>
    <td>Hockey</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>DATE FRIDAY</td>
    <td>Rugby</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>DATE OF SATURDAY</td>
    <td>Football</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td>DATE OF SUNDAY</td>
    <td>Basketball</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now what I need is, I can store the value of current date in **$date** but how I can use it to change everyday according to the day, i.e the dates should be updated according to the day.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th id="1">Day</th>
        <th id="1">Date</th>
        <th>Game</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>20-08-2018</td> <!-- coming monday's date-->
        <td>Golf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>14-08-2018</td> <!-- today's date-->
        <td>Swimming</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>15-08-2018</td>
        <td>Tennis</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>16-08-2018</td>
        <td>Hockey</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td>17-08-2018</td>
        <td>Rugby</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Saturday</td>
        <td>18-08-2018</td>
        <td>Football</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sunday</td>
        <td>19-08-2018</td>
        <td>Basketball</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm a newbie to php, also looked for some solutions over stack overflow , there was a solution regarding how to extract the date from day name , but I think this thing is quite different from that, correct me if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Your two elements cannot have the same **id**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the date of next monday, tuesday, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188728/get-the-date-of-next-monday-tuesday-etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use This code to dynamically update content each new day:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    </head>
                    <body>

                    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

                    <table>
                    <tr id="1">
                    <th >Day</th>
                    <th >Date</th>
                    <th>Game</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $array=array('Monday'=>'Golf','Tuesday'=>'Swimming','Wednesday'=>'Tennis','Thursday'=>'Hockey','Friday'=>'Rugby','Saturday'=>'Football','Sunday'=>'Basketball');
                    $start=date_create();
                    $end=clone($start);
                    $end->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
                    $period = new DatePeriod($start,date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'), $end);
                    foreach($period as $k=> $date){
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $date->format("l");?></td>
                            <?php if($k===0):?> 
                                <td class="today" style="background:green;"><?php echo $date->format("d-m-Y");?></td> 
                            <?php else:?>
                                <td class="followingday" style="background:gray;"><?php echo $date->format("d-m-Y");?></td> 
                            <?php endif;?>
                            <td><?php echo $array[$date->format("l")];?></td>
                          </tr>
                            <?php

                    }
                    ?>
                    </table>

                    </body>
                    </html>
```

The code above print the date starting from the current date but  you can use the code below to keep date starting from Monday:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    </head>
                    <body>

                    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

                    <table>
                    <tr id="1">
                    <th >Day</th>
                    <th >Date</th>
                    <th>Game</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $array=array('Monday'=>'Golf','Tuesday'=>'Swimming','Wednesday'=>'Tennis','Thursday'=>'Hockey','Friday'=>'Rugby','Saturday'=>'Football','Sunday'=>'Basketball');
                    $start=date_create();
                    $end=clone($start);
                    $end->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
                    $period = new DatePeriod($start,date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'), $end);

                    foreach($period as $key=>$date){
                        $date_period[$date->format('l')]=$date;
                    }
                    unset($period);
                    foreach($array as $day=>$sport){
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $day;?></td>
                            <?php if($day===$start->format('l')):?> 
                                <td class="today" style="background:green;"><?php echo $date_period[$day]->format("d-m-Y");?></td> 
                            <?php else:?>
                                <td class="followingday" style="background:gray;"><?php echo  $date_period[$day]->format("d-m-Y");?></td> 
                            <?php endif;?>
                            <td><?php echo $sport;?></td>
                          </tr>
                            <?php

                    }
                    ?>
                    </table>

                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hold it this way:

```
$next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' +1 day'));
```

or use **for loop** to generate x days ahead:

`$next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' +$i day'));`

Comment: but how that date will  be printed in that html tag, providing it should be updated daily according to the day

Comment: echo $date; for a specific part of the page, you want to show the value. Every time you enter the page, php script will generate $date one more time

Comment: Hi, double quote is needed to parse $i `$next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date ." +{$i} day"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $week_days=['Monday'=>7,'Tuesday'=>1,'Wednesday'=>2,'Thursday'=>3,'Friday'=>4,'Saturday'=>5,'Sunday'=>6];
    $current_day=date('l');
    $current_date=date('Y-m-d');
    $days_to_munus=0;
    switch ($current_day) {
        case 'Monday':
            $days_to_munus=0;
            break;
        case 'Tuesday':
            $days_to_munus=1;
            break;
        case 'Wednesday':
            $days_to_munus=2;
            break;
        case 'Thursday':
            $days_to_munus=3;
            break;
        case 'Friday':
            $days_to_munus=4;
            break;
        case 'Saturday':
            $days_to_munus=5;
            break;
        case 'Sunday':
            $days_to_munus=6;
            break;      
        default:
            $days_to_munus=0;
            break;
    }

?>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th id="1">Day</th>
        <th id="1">Date</th>
        <th>Game</th>
      </tr>
<?php

    foreach ($week_days as $key => $value) {
        $minus_days=$value-$days_to_munus;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$key</td>";
        echo "<td>".date('d-m-Y', strtotime($current_date ." $minus_days day"))."</td>";
        echo "<td>game_name</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

?>

</table>
```

Try this , hope this code will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way:

```
<?php

$dow = date('l');
$game = array(
    'Monday'    => 'Golf',
    'Tuesday'   => 'Swimming',
    'Wednesday' => 'Tennis',
    'Thursday'  => 'Hockey',
    'Friday'    => 'Rugby',
    'Saturday'  => 'Football',
    'Sunday'    =>  'Basketball'
);

echo "
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
<tr>
    <th id='1' class='1'>Day</th>
    <th id='2' class='1'>Date</th>
    <th>Game</th>
</tr>
";
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($week); $i++ ) {
    $ctr_dow = date('l',strtotime("$i days"));

    echo "
    <tr>
        <th>" . $ctr_dow . "</th>
        <th>" .  date('m-d-Y',strtotime("$i days")) . "</th>
        <th>" . $game[$ctr_dow] . "</th>
    </tr>";

}

echo "
</table>
";
?>
```

Also, I hope you don't mind me changing the id tags of the table head.