# PHP dynamic calander

Tags: php, date

Im trying to make a calander in php (for school). it has to be made 100% generated values. I can do that but I cant figure out how to make it start on monday. It has to be made with only php and html,so no js css or sql is allowed to make it easier.  I'm probaly doing everything wrong here but if anyone knows how I can make a calander, all help is welcome.  (:

```
<?php
$D1 = date("l-j-m");
$D2 = date("l-j-m", strtotime("+ 1 days"));
$D3 = date("l-j-m", strtotime("+ 2 days"));
$D4 = date("l-j-m", strtotime("+ 3 days"));
$D5 = date("l-j-m", strtotime("+ 4 days"));
$D6 = date("l-j-m", strtotime("+ 5 days"));
$D7 = date("l-j-m", strtotime("+ 6 days"));

$U1 = date("g-a");
$U2 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 1 hours"));
$U3 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 2 hours"));
$U4 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 3 hours"));
$U5 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 4 hours"));
$U6 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 5 hours"));
$U7 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 6 hours"));
$U8 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 1 hours"));
$U9 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 2 hours"));
$U10 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 3 hours"));
$U11 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 4 hours"));
$U12= date("g-a", strtotime("+ 5 hours"));
$U13 = date("g-a", strtotime("+ 6 hours"));

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Recept 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="solid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><?php echo($D1); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo($D2); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo($D3); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo($D4); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo($D5); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo($D6); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo($D7); ?></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U1); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U2); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U3); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U4); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U5); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U6) ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U7); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U8); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1<?php echo($U9); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U10); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U11); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($U12); ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried to get this done? There's no ocde given to check for a monday, or to get the date of the next/last monday

Comment: Im a big php noob (first year of my class, can u explain what you mean or give me some keywoards so I can google it?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188728/get-the-date-of-next-monday-tuesday-etc?

Comment: There is thing in programming called DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). The problem with repeating yourself means you have to perform adjustments multiple times as well in case you decide to make changes to your code. Learn to use loops, and arrays. It will make your (programmer) life easier.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following HTML template along with the PHP code below - not the most elegant solution but should be simple enough for understanding by a newbie:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
th.br_bot
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
}

th.br_btr
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
}

td.week_num
{
    font-size: 9pt;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    padding: 2px;
}

td.day
{
    font-size: 9pt;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td.day_red
{
    font-size: 9pt;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #EFC2C3;
}

td.day_blue
{
    font-size: 9pt;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #B6CBEF;
}

span.week_day
{
    color: black;
}

span.week_end
{
    color: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="cal" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-left:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;">
    <tr style="font-size:9pt;" bgcolor="#D6B695">
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;JANUARY&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;FEBRUARY&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;MARCH&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;APRIL&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>{SECTION_1}</td></tr>

    <tr style="font-size:9pt;" bgcolor="#D6B695">
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;MAY&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;JUNE&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;JULY&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;AUGUST&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>{SECTION_2}</td></tr>

    <tr style="font-size:9pt;" bgcolor="#D6B695">
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;SEPTEMBER&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;OCTOBER&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;NOVEMBER&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="8" class="br_btr">&nbsp;DECEMBER&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
        <th class="br_bot">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="br_bot">M</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">W</th>
        <th class="br_bot">T</th>
        <th class="br_bot">F</th>
        <th class="br_bot">S</th>
        <th class="br_btr">S</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>{SECTION_3}</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php

// returns HTML for the given month
function month_calendar($year,$month)
{
    $my_time = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year); // Unix timestamp for the beginning of the month
    $start_day = date('N', $my_time);
    $start_week = (int)date('W',$my_time); // because date returns zero-padded value
    $daysInMonth = date('t',$my_time); // how many days in the given month
    $dayNumber = date('z',$my_time) + 1; // day of the year for the 1st date of the month (0 - 365)

    $output = Array();
    // show first week
    $current_week = '<td align="center" class="week_num">'.($start_week++).'</td>';
    if($start_week > 52) $start_week = 1;

    $dayOfWeek = 1;
    while($dayOfWeek < $start_day)
    {
      // show empty cells until we reach the start of the month
        $current_week .= '<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>';
        $dayOfWeek++;
    }
    $dayOfMonth = 1;
    while($dayOfWeek <= 7)
    {
        $current_week .= '<td class="day"><span class="week_'.($dayOfWeek > 5 ? 'end' : 'day').'" style="padding:2px">'.($dayOfMonth++).'</span></td>';
        $dayOfWeek++;
        $dayNumber++;
    }
    $output[] = $current_week;

    while($dayOfMonth <= $daysInMonth)
    {
      $current_week = '<td align="center" class="week_num">'.($start_week++).'</td>';
        if($start_week > 52) $start_week = 1;
        $dayOfWeek = 1;
        while($dayOfWeek <= 7)
        {
            if($dayOfMonth <= $daysInMonth) $current_week .= '<td class="day"><span class="week_'.($dayOfWeek > 5 ? 'end' : 'day').'" style="padding:2px">'.($dayOfMonth++).'</span></td>';
                else $current_week .= '<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>'; // show empty cells after the end of the month
            $dayOfWeek++;
            $dayNumber++;
        }
        $output[] = $current_week;
    }
    return $output;
}

// returns HTML for 4 months - starting at the given month/year
function section($year,$month)
{
    $month_1 = month_calendar($year, $month);
    $month_2 = month_calendar($year, $month + 1);
    $month_3 = month_calendar($year, $month + 2);
    $month_4 = month_calendar($year, $month + 3);
    $max_weeks = max(
      count($month_1),
      count($month_2),
      count($month_3),
      count($month_4)
    );
    $empty_week = '';
    for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) // 7 days + a cell for the week number
        $empty_week .= '<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>';
    $output = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $max_weeks; $i++)
    {
        $output .= '<tr>';
        $output .= $month_1[$i] != '' ? $month_1[$i] : $empty_week;
        $output .= $month_2[$i] != '' ? $month_2[$i] : $empty_week;
        $output .= $month_3[$i] != '' ? $month_3[$i] : $empty_week;
        $output .= $month_4[$i] != '' ? $month_4[$i] : $empty_week;
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
    return $output;
}

    if($template = @file_get_contents('/tempates/calendar.html'))
    {
        // show calendar
        $cal_year = 2020;
        $template = str_replace('<tr><td>{SECTION_1}</td></tr>',section($cal_year,1),$template);
        $template = str_replace('<tr><td>{SECTION_2}</td></tr>',section($cal_year,5),$template);
        $template = str_replace('<tr><td>{SECTION_3}</td></tr>',section($cal_year,9),$template);
        echo $template;
    }
    else die('Could not find template - calendar.html');
?>
```